# Type test case doesn't catch the defined constraints symfony2

Tags: forms, unit-testing, symfony, constraints

I have UserTypeTest extended from TypeTestCase

```
<?php

class UserTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
        public function testSubmitInvalidData()
        {
            $formData = array(
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '123456',
                'email' => '',
                'firstName' => '',
                'lastName' => '',
                'roles' => array(
                )
            );

            $form = $this->factory->create(new UserType());
            $form->submit($formData);
            $this->assertTrue(!$form->isValid());
        }
    }
```

And UserType Class has some constraints in buildForm() function (username not blank).
How to pass the assertTrue with $form->isValid() in my test case? $form->isValid() return true always

Comment: [from the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html): Don't test the validation: it is applied by a listener that is not active in the test case and it relies on validation configuration. Instead, unit test your custom constraints directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to test the validation is on entity, I write the constraints on entities directly and it words greatly